# Open Media Uploader Link in single post or page

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, media-modal

I want to open the media Upload Window like in a single post or page.
It is important for me, to have that menu on top, which filters the media Library:

[image]

This is my current code, which allows only to filter by date:

```
$('.tc_upload_img_btn').live('click', function( event ){
        var parent_wrapper  = $(this).parent('td').parent().parent().parent().parent();
        var field           = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('input[type="text"]');
        var button          = $(this);
        var multi           = false;
        var absolute_link   = $(this).attr( 'data-allow-multi' );

        if( $(this).attr( 'data-allow-multi' ) == "true" ){
            multi   = true; 
        }

        var insertImage = wp.media.controller.Library.extend({
            defaults :  _.defaults({
                    id:        'insert-image',
                    frame:      'post',
                    title:      'Datei wählen',
                    allowLocalEdits: true,
                    displaySettings: true,
                    displayUserSettings: true,
                    multiple : true/*,
                    type : 'image'//audio, video, application/pdf, ... etc*/
              }, wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults )
        });

        var frame = wp.media({
            button : { text : 'Select' },
            frame:  'post',
            state : 'insert-image',//gallery-edit
            states : [
                new insertImage()
            ],
            library : { type : 'image'}
        });

        frame.open(button); 
)}
```

Which param do I need to add, to get the other filter (red marked in the screen)?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it:

```
var frame = wp.media({
            button : { text : 'Wählen' },
            frame:  'post'/*,
            state : 'insert-image',//gallery-edit
            states : [
                new insertImage()
            ],
            library : { type : 'image'}*/
        });
```